# Undefined property: stdClass::$signature_id - LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

[image: This is my database]
[image: The error here]
This is the error from my controller code, it was undefined can you help me find the error or my coding that I missed
**My controller:**

```php
function editor_edit_page($id)
{
    $designs = DB::table('designs')
        ->join('seminars', 'designs.seminar_id', '=', 'seminars.seminar_id')
        ->where('design_id', '=', $id)
        ->select("*")
        ->get();


    $logo = DB::table('logo')
        ->where('logo_id', '=', $designs[0]->logo_id)
        ->select("*")
        ->get();

    $signature = DB::table('signature')
        ->where('signature_id', '=', $designs[0]->signature_id) //error is here
        ->select("*")
        ->get();

    $baseimage = DB::table('base_image')
        ->where('baseimage_id', '=', $designs[0]->baseimage_id)
        ->select("*")
        ->get();

    $logoall = DB::table('logo')
        ->select("*")
        ->get();

    $signatureall = DB::table('signature')
        ->select("*")
        ->get();

    $baseimageall = DB::table('base_image')
        ->select("*")
        ->get();

    return view('editor.editor_editpage', [
        'logo' => $logo,
        'designs' => $designs,
        'signature' => $signature,
        'baseimage' => $baseimage,
        'logoall' => $logoall,
        'signatureall' => $signatureall,
        'baseimageall' => $baseimageall
    ]);
}
```

I am expecting it would be a defined propety because it was present in my database I don't know what is the problem. I need help please...

Comment: Try logging the `$designs` variable and see whether you get the `$signature_id` property with it.

Comment: You should always first `isset` check array index exists or not (or the query returns empty `$designs[0]` then proceed using it. Also, try using `dd` for debugging for such specific error message `dd(designs[0])` and check `signature_id` exists or not.

Comment: Kindly add the output of ``dd($designs);``

Comment: Trying to Undefined property means you are trying to access that column which is not               fetched or you misspelled

Comment: show me seminars and designs tables schema

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are getting collection object when you use get()

If you want to access all records of a particular table from Eloquent Object then use foreach loop on that object and you will get your value.

for example

```php
foreach($designs as $d){
     echo $d->Property_Name;
}
```